# Android: Start Async Task in OnReceive Method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I currently have a Service which manages a Broadcast Receiver. This receiver can be turned off and on.

At the moment the OnReceive is triggered when a SMS is received. It then uploads the SMS to a server. The code works fine, but I heard from 3.0 above network connections need to be ran on Async task. Even if this isn't the case I would like to move the upload to another thread, so the upload task can't block the UI thread. (I have tired to move the Service to an IntentService, this causes the broadcast Receiver leak)

```
          SMSBR = new BroadcastReceiver(){

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //START OF ONRECIVER************************
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

                String strMessage = "";

                if ( extras != null )
                {
                    Object[] smsextras = (Object[]) extras.get( "pdus" );

                    for ( int i = 0; i < smsextras.length; i++ )
                    {
                        SmsMessage smsmsg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsextras[i]);

                        String strMsgBody = smsmsg.getMessageBody().toString();
                        String strMsgSrc = smsmsg.getOriginatingAddress();

                        strMessage += "SMS from " + strMsgSrc + " : " + strMsgBody;                    

                        Log.d("Message", "is "+strMessage);
                        //***************************************************************
                        InputStream is = null;
                        try{
                            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mayar.abertay.ac.uk/~1001077/insert.php");

                            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DeviceNumber", telephonyManager.getLine1Number().toString()));
                                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SenderNumber", strMsgSrc));
                                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Message", strMsgBody));
                                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                                is = entity.getContent();
                                Log.d("is = ", is.toString());
                                Log.d("In SMS", "Sender success");
                                  if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) {
                                        Log.d("Message upload Running", "on UI");
                                    } else {
                                        Log.d("Message upload NOT running", "on UIx");
                                    }

                        }catch (Exception e){
                            Log.e("Log_tag", "Error in http sms " + e.toString());
                            Log.d("In SMS", "Sender NOT success");
                        }
                        //****************************************************************

                    }

                }
                //END OF ON RECEIVE****************************
            }


          };
```

Comment: What is the question? How to put this in an AsyncTask? Or IF you should use an AsyncTask? If an AsyncTask can be started from a call to onReceive()?

Comment: @baske How can I get the upload running in an AsyncTask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer your question without talking about AsyncTasks:
Take a look at

> BroadcastReceiver.registerReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver,
>   IntentFilter filter, String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler)

I found that while I was checking some documentation on BroadcastReceivers and looks like exactly what you need (check [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Handler%29)). One more hint: use it in combination with a `HandlerThread`.